# Unable to connect to exchange server using power shell

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to connect to Office 365 Exchange server using power shell.I am using below given command to connect

```
$cred=Get-Credential

$ses=New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

But i am getting error as below

```
New-PSSession : 
[outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Basic
authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: As the error states, the endpoint doesn't support basic authentication. Please [refer to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-microsoft-365-with-microsoft-365-powershell) for instructions on how to obtain a remote session.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use Modern Authentication:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Office-365-Connection-47e03052

Answer (score 0):

Windows Remote Management (WinRM) needs to allow basic authentication to create Exchange session. If basic authentication is disabled, you’ll get the mentioned error when you try to connect.

To check whether the basic authentication is enabled, run below command in command prompt.

`winrm get winrm/config/client/auth`

If Basic= true not set, you need to run below command to enable basic authentication.

`winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}`

Comment: I got it fixed l. Thank you for the help